# VPN / SignalR not working together. what can i do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, vpn, windows-server-2019

Have a server with a public IP address and windows server 2019. configured a VPN and when I try to access it through the VPN, signalR is not working.

if I access it through the public IP address it works. 
I've got the firewall in off position.

[image: working version of site]

if I go through the VPN it doesn't work.

[image: non-working version.. and crome gives information connecting...]

more information:

- all files are in the webserver (js )
- doesn't give any error
- I cannot see in Fidler anything strange.
- VPN don't provide internet access.

Answer (score 0):

See if the ports signalR is using are not blocked in firewall or VPN

Comment: firewall is off .. going to see on the vpn